# Array length is not equal to array objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

The code below basically iterates through dropped files, pushes the file object into the filesArray and appends the file to the DOM if they meet the **criteria (less than 1mb and are png/jpg/fig)**.  I have set the allowed fileSize to 1MB.

```
for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
        if (validateType(files[i].type)){
            //alert("ok");
            if (files[i].size < allowedSize){

        filesArray[i]=files[i];
        var reader = new FileReader();
        a = 0;
        reader.onload = function (event) {

            var image = new Image();
            image.src = event.target.result;
            //image.width = 100; // a fake resize
            imageBoxWrapper = $("<span />", {id: "idw"+a,class: "imageBoxWrapper"});
            imageBox = $("<span />", {id: "idb"+a,class: "imageBox"});

            complete = imageBox.append(image);
            $(complete).appendTo(imageBoxWrapper);

            newimageBox = $(imageBoxWrapper).append("<span class='imageDelete' imageIndex="+a+"><img src='images/icons/cross.png'> Delete</span>");

            $(newimageBox).appendTo("#dropZone");
            a++;
        };  

    reader.readAsDataURL(files[i]);
           } //end size validation
            else{
                oversize = true;
                overzsizefiles += files[i].name+" is bigger than 1Mb \n";
            }
    } // end type validation
    else{
        found = true;
        unAllowedFiles += files[i].name+" is not allowed \n";;
    } 
  }
```

When I drop files larger than 1 MB, they are not appended to the DOM however when I console.log(filesArray) the length is for all files. E.g

```
a.png > 1 MB
b.png > 512KB
c.png > 256KB

Alert will be thrown for a.png that it is oversize, 
b.png and c.png will be appended to DOM,
console.log(fileArray) outputs [1: file, 2; file]
console.log(fileArray) output 3
```

Since `filesArray[i]=files[i]` is declared within if block `if (files[i].size < allowedSize)`, I would have expected the array length to be 2

Comment: An array is zero based, if you have a value at index 2, the length will be 3 ([0,1,2]), regardless of the number of items in the array.

Comment: @adeneo: Thanks for your response. Now I get it!! So a workaround would be to push from index 0 only if there is a value!

Comment: Indeed, just use push() if a condition is met, and the index takes care of it self, and the length will be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing `filesArray[i] = files[i];` so if the last item passed the size test, then `filesArray` will be set to be the full length, even if some items in between were not assigned.  Javascript `.length` reports one higher than the highest array element assigned.

In this simple test, you can see what is going on:

```
var x = [];
x[10] = "foo";
alert(x.length);    // alerts 11
```

---

To fix it, you probably want to change:

```
filesArray[i]=files[i];
```

to this:

```
filesArray.push(files[i]);
```

Then, `filesArray` will ONLY have in it the items that passed the size test and it's length will match the number of items it has in it.